# tar extract after creating directory name based on tar file

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have different zipped(tgz) files I want to create a directory name with zipped file name and move that zipped file into their respective folder and unzip them there.

Example:-

I have two zipped files,

```
   email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-01-22-00-01.tgz
   email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-02-22-00-01.tgz
   email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-03-22-00-01.tgz
```

I want to create first directory like this,

```
   email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-01-22-00-01
   email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-02-22-00-01
   email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-03-22-00-01
```

move that zipped files into respected folders and then unzip them.Got stucked please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU `tar` has a `-C` (aka `--directory`) option to change directory before doing anything with the tar file.  With that, you could do something like this:

```
for t in *.tgz ; do
  bn="$(basename "$t" .tgz)"
  mkdir -p "$bn"
  tar xfz "$t" -C "$bn" 
  mv "$t" "$bn"
done
```

Comment: Check the order of command line flags there: `tar xzf "$bn" -C "$t"`

Comment: @Kusalananda almost right.  $t is the tarfile.  $bn is the basename.    tar's `f` option  requires the next arg to be the tar file (i often forget this on first attempt).  `tar xzf "$bn" -C "$t` won't work, but `tar xfz "$t" -C "$bn"` will.

Comment: @cas-Thnxs but it is not unzipping my tar file only it created directory and moved it to respected directory.

Comment: @cas Duh. Got the variables backwards.

Comment: @krishnakumar did you use the original version i posted, or the updated version?   As Kusalananda pointed out, the tarfile has to come immediately after tar's `f` option.  My original version had the `-C "$bn"` in the wrong place.

Comment: @cas-Thanxs!!it really help me!!

Answer (score 1):

```console
$ tar -xf email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-01-22-00-01.tgz --one-top-level
$ tar -xf email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-02-22-00-01.tgz --one-top-level
$ tar -xf email_raw_data_latest-2017-08-03-22-00-01.tgz --one-top-level
```

**--one-top-level**[=DIR] 
Extract all files into DIR, or, if used without argument, into a subdirectory named by the base name of the archive (minus standard compression suffixes recognizable by --auto-compress).